# How to focus highchart navigator and graph to a part of the resultset

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am running my highchart through php, and I give my highchart graph input through php/sql. I am interested though to be able to focus (limit) the view of the graph to a part of the complete graph, e.g. after a refresh.

I am mostly using the line graph. I often generate for example 30 days of data and then use the zoom function / navigator to zoom into parts of the graph. I then click on a "dot" and my issue is that this refreshes my browser and I have to zoom in again after this has been done.

My thought was if you are able to store a cookie or similar to identify the view of the graph (start/end) of the focus AND you are able to set a variable for highchart defining the zoom (e.g. start/end of the resultset) or similar, then I would be able to solve my challenge (since I can generate highchart code through php).

Well I hope you understand my question - and I am looking forward to hear from you all :)

Cheers Nikolaj

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you expect by saving chart `x-axis` extremes in local storage or as a cookie. When the chart is loaded check the cookie and if it exists set x-axis extremes. Check the minimal demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
function saveExtremes(min, max) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();

  document.cookie = `minX=${min}; ${expires}`;
  document.cookie = `maxX=${max}; ${expires}`;
}

function getExtremes() {
  var cookies = document.cookie.split('; '),
    min,
    max;

  cookies.forEach(function(cookie) {
    if (cookie.indexOf('minX=') !== -1) {
      min = +(cookie.replace('minX=', ''));
    } else if (cookie.indexOf('maxX=') !== -1) {
      max = +(cookie.replace('maxX=', ''));
    }
  });

  return {
    min,
    max
  }
}

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          extremes = getExtremes(),
          H = Highcharts;

        if (H.defined(extremes.min) && H.defined(extremes.max)) {
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremes.min, extremes.max);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(2, 5);
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      571,
      696,
      970,
      119,
      137,
      154
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      234,
      123,
      444,
      322,
      543,
      657
    ]
  }],
});

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();

  saveExtremes(extremes.min, extremes.max);
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/06jmz5ve/1/